# PowerShell command to grab file from SFTP site error downloadfile

Tags: powershell

I want to call this Sftp site too grab all files in the folder "data" when it run and I have download posh-ssh model, when I run it am getting

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

```
$ftp = "sftp://test/data" 
$user = "user" 
$pass = "PasswordTest"
$remoteDropDir = 'C:\test'
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)   
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $ftp, $remoteDropDir)
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at the MS Documentation regarding the parameters supplied for the `DownloadFile()` method. It's expecting a file name, not a directory.

Comment: You might want to have a look at some of the FTP modules that are available out there.  [WinSCP seems promising](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinSCP/5.17.10.0)